# ASP.NET Master/Detail filtering stuck

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, drop-down-menu, adventureworks

I have Microsoft's AdventureWorks database. I need to filter `ProductCategory` table and `Product` table via two dropdownlists. I have to use `SqlDataSource` or `LinqDataSource`.

First list: `SqlDataSource` -> Specify custom SQL statment I've added a `ProductCategory` table and selected `Name`, `ProductCategoryID` and i've enabled autopostback. Works fine.

Second list. `SqlDataSource` -> Specify custom SQL statment I've added a `Product` table and selected `Name` and `ProductID`. Where can I define the parameters for `list2` to look at `list1`. Cant get this option:

[image: option info]

I tried with [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581789.aspx).

Searching in .net for Dummies but with no sucess.